# Para que serve o prefixo "blob:" na URL?

Tags: html, url

Eu venho encontrando constantemente em alguns sites o prefixo `blob:` antes da URL especialmente sites que apontam para arquivos de mídia como imagens e vídeos que é o caso, por exemplo, do site [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) que utiliza praticamente em todos os seus ícones a serem baixados o conjunto `blob:` + URL:

```html
<a href="blob:https://fontawesome.com/d27060f2-bbbb-473d-87d4-3e08090a642b">Abrir imagem SVG</a>
```

Eu gostaria de entender qual é a utilidade deste prefixo `blob:` na URL e também se ele é utilizado apenas em links, visto que o link acima não vai abrir, por conta, do `blob:` estar impedindo que a página atual seja direcionada para um novo destino.